# IntentService does not get started

Tags: java, android

I'm making an android application which uses it's own Camera activity. The images are then stored on the local SQLite database by using an IntentService.

Problem now is: the IntentService doesn't get started after the picture is taken. When using this IntentService on other occations it works perfect so I am at a loss on the why it is not working...

Below is the code used in my CameraActivity to take a picture and start the IntentService.

```
mPicture = getPictureCallback();
mRaw = getRawCallback();
mShutter = getShutterCallback();
mCamera.takePicture(mShutter, mRaw, mPicture);

private PictureCallback getPictureCallback() {
    PictureCallback picture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Picture taken, starting service");
            Intent databaseIntent = new Intent(MyCameraActivity.this, DBHandlerService.class);
            databaseIntent.putExtra("image", data);
            databaseIntent.putExtra("action", "save");
            databaseIntent.putExtra(AppConstant.RESULT_RECEIVER, mReceiver);
            startService(databaseIntent);
            mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
        }


    };
    return picture;
}
```

The onHandleEvent:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onHandle started");

    Database db = getDB();
    action = intent.getStringExtra("action");
    Bundle resultbundle = new Bundle();

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onHandleIntent action : " + action);

    final ResultReceiver reciever = intent
            .getParcelableExtra(AppConstant.RESULT_RECEIVER);

    reciever.send(STATUS_RUNNING, Bundle.EMPTY);
//Different actions depending on the "action" string
    if(action.equals("xxxxx"){
        //perform action
    } else {
        // inform activity the requested action does not exist. When
        // STATUS_ERROR is received they must check if errorcode is not
        // null.
        resultbundle.putString("errormsg", "No actions undertaken");
        resultbundle.putInt("errorcode", 9999);
        reciever.send(STATUS_ERROR, resultbundle);
    }
}
```

I also use this IntentService to get all the pictures from the database. Since the DB stays empty no images are returned but every log gets printed.
If i try it to save the image the logs inside the IntentService are nevr printed.

If more code is needed, let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Thomas

Comment: Logs of picture taken and IntentService are coming  in logcat ? any specific error ? Please also share onHandleIntent.

Comment: Ok, apparently i get a "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION" right after my "picture taken, starting service"-log. This apparently can get caused by to much data into a bundle, i'm searching how to fix this atm..